# Project outside my solution's directory not showing source control (local Git)

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs

I opened a project in directory dev/proj1 and it is under local Git source ctrl with Git added via a solution in that directory, using VS2013.

I have another solution under dev/sol2/proj2 that is under local Git source control. I added it to source control in the same way.

I added proj1 to the sol2. It is missing the source control, and there is no File->Source-Control menu when I'm standing on proj1 in Visual Studio.

- Note: This is **NOT** a duplicate of the StackOverflow issue
  *[Git in Visual Studio - add existing project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824994/git-in-visual-studio-add-existing-project)* or the likes.

What can I do?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using git via the command line, rather than in an IDE, there's a slightly steeper learning curve, but issues like this disappear, and you have much, much more control over what's happening.

Comment: How did you judge the project  in source control  or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the menu `File->Source-Control` you mentioned above is the same as below picture. Then there is no Source Control menu item under File for Git. It’s a normal phenomenon. This menu item is **only for TFVC**.
[image]

If the projcet has a padlock icon in solution means it has been in source control. You can also double check it through your **Web Portal**(Code→Git→Your solution). 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I thought Git solutions had the same UI as TFS solutions. 

In the meantime I simply created a new solution with all projects under it in the directory tree. Renamed the solutions and the namespaces (including default namespace in the project properties) accordingly.

Comment: Git maintains a hierachial folder from a 'base', typically the folder where your MainApplication.sln or whatever your solution is name resides. Only way to include external folders in windows is via directory symbolic links, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(v=ws.11).aspx